# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Politics Stack Exchange](http://politics.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why can public employees unionize?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/why-can-public-employees-unionize)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What kind of country would offer Snowden the most secure asylum?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/what-kind-of-country-would-offer-snowden-the-most-secure-asylum)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why is the cost of food stamps 10 times higher than in 1938 in real dollars?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/why-is-the-cost-of-food-stamps-10-times-higher-than-in-1938-in-real-dollars)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How is an employed person defined for OECD countries?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/how-is-an-employed-person-defined-for-oecd-countries)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is considered due process of law in the 5th amendment in the US Constitution?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/what-is-considered-due-process-of-law-in-the-5th-amendment-in-the-us-constitutio)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Are laws restricting electoral oversight to particular parties constitutional?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/are-laws-restricting-electoral-oversight-to-particular-parties-constitutional)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What share of federal tax breaks do the rich get?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/what-share-of-federal-tax-breaks-do-the-rich-get)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Do any countries have Country of Origin Food Labeling laws?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/do-any-countries-have-country-of-origin-food-labeling-laws)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Did the British government call American revolutionaries terrorists?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1698/did-the-british-government-call-american-revolutionaries-terrorists)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why is Sweden's employment rate so high?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/why-is-swedens-employment-rate-so-high)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)